# why data event not working on http.get response stream

Tags: node.js, stream

Handling images in nodejs, I got stuck on an issue that the `data` event is not working with piped response stream.

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url');
var httpServer = http.createServer(function(req,res){
        var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        var fstream = $.FS.createReadStream('/root/image'+path);
        fstream.on('error',function(){
            res.writeHead(404);
            return res.end();
        });
        fstream.pipe(res);
});
httpServer.listen(8080);
http.get({
      host : '127.0.0.1',
      port : 8080,
      path : '/image.jpg'
},function(res){
      res.on('data',function(){
           console.log('data received'); //nothing happened
      });
}).on('error',function(er){
      throw er;
});
```

Did I do anything wrong? Or is this a node bug?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing if the response has a status of 304 (not modified), then no `data` event is fired. The solution is fairly easy if you are not afraid of the terminal (or command line in Windows). Open your command tool and `cd` to the directory containing your image.  Once there, you can use the following command to make it appear that your file has been updated (replace `filename.ext` with the name of your file):

#### Unix/Linux

```
touch filename.ext
```

#### Windows

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

To rerun the command, hit the <kbd>↑</kbd> up arrow and then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>